# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 1135-1137: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python, html, css, django, pdf

I'm trying in Django to render from html to pdf a monthly report that takes data from a database
in Hebrew.
I have a problem that I have not been able to fix for several days.
When I display data in English the pdf works properly and everything is fine, but when I want to display data in the Hebrew language from the database, it does not allow me and the following error appears: **'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 1135-1137: ordinal not in range(256)**

I have already tried a several solutions:

1. I changed the font several times in the base html of the PDF via the css and it just does not help at all.
2. I tried to change the rendering function I have at the moment and it also did not help at all.

My rendering function :

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```